# How to pass values to an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive that I want to pass a value, but it does not work:

```
<p>{{testvar}}</p>
<my-fn info="{{testvar}}"></my-fn>

app.directive('myFn', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/my-fn.html',
        scope: {
            info: "=info"
        }
    };
});
```

my-fn.html:

```
<p>the value is: {{info}}</p>
```

Result:
The value in `<p>` tag is shown correctly, but the `my-fn` directive is not shown and prints the following error in the console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Btestvar%7D
J/<@http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js:6:416
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question: one has to neglect the curly brakets as follows:

```
<my-fn info="testvar"></my-fn>
```

If anyone knows *why*, please comment below.

Comment: Check all this stuff: https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2e1h35/can_somebody_explain_when_to_use_curly_brackets/